# DataTables: Pressing enter key in order to use pagination with a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I have succesfully implemented the DataTables (version 1.10+) pagination plugin with textbox but I would like to allow the user to first enter a page number and then to press the enter key. By default, instantly the user is taken to the page but, as stated above, I would like to allow to write first a number with in the textbox and then jump to the page by using the enter key. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Can we see a fiddle/existing code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [**input pagination plugin**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination/input) :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   pagingType: "input"
})
```

example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bqpt85LL/**

It does not support "jump to the page by using the enter key" out of the box, but you can easily refactor the code.  Look at the source around line #164 (in function `$(nInput).keyup(function (e) {`.. ). Change

```
fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
```

to

```
if (e.which === 13) fnCallbackDraw(oSettings);
```

That should be it. Have not tested it but this is certainly the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Input datatable page plugin: you just need to add "pagingType: "input" while constructing your datatable.

javascript :

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        pagingType: "input"
    } );
```

Then add this Js file :

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/pagination/input.js"></script>
```

For demo

https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/ebRXw/2231/